# How can I create a formatted string out of a block of html?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, outlook, string-formatting

I need to provide a variable bit of data (the "body" of an email) to a (string) member of a list of string, and am trying to build it using string.format, but I get, "*) expected*" on the "http" part here:

```
string htmlBodyAmalgamation = string.Format(@"<html><body><img src=\"http://www.platypus.com/wp-
content/themes/platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Platypus logo\" width=\"199\" height=\"130\" ><p>{0}</p>", body);
```

I get that err msg whether I have 0, 1, 2, or 3 backwhacks ("\") prepended to the "http".

If there is no variable portion (if the body is static/known in advance) I can do this:

```
List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
    {
        "<html><body><img src=\"http://www.platypus.com/wp-content/themes/platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Platypus logo\" width=\"199\" height=\"130\" ><p>Your Platypus Price Push report is attached.</p>",
        "</body></html>"
    };
mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, htmlBody.ToArray());
```

...and it works fine.

So it's trying to embed the variable "body" value via string.format as follows that is proving problematic:

```
string htmlBodyAmalgamation = string.Format(@"<html><body><img src=\"http://www.platypus.com/wp-content/themes/platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Platypus logo\" width=\"199\" height=\"130\" ><p>Your Platypus Price Push report is attached.</p>", body);
List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
    {
        htmlBodyAmalgamation,
        "</body></html>"
    };
```

What's the trick to get the html and string.format to work together?

Comment: In your last example, you're using the verbatim operator `@` and escaping with \. In those strings you would actually escape `"` with `"` making it `""`.

Comment: Using single quotes seems simpler and appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough - use single quotes instead of double, and omit the backwhacks:

```
string htmlBodyAmalgamation = string.Format(@"<html><body><img src='http://www.platypus.com/wp-content/themes/platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png' alt='Platypus logo' width='199' height='130' ><p>{0}</p>", body);
```

Simpler yet, I can cut out some of the middlemen and just do this:

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Format(@"<html><body><img src='http://www.platypus.com/wp-content/themes/platypus/images/pa_logo_notag.png' alt='Platypus logo' width='199' height='130' ><p>{0}</p></body></html>", body);
```

Comment: For a simple html contents using string format is completely OK, however for complicated scenarios like email templates consider using [run-time T4 templates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd share an elegant solution that I used a year or so ago.
We used HTML templates for e-mails as well and, found that the Razor engine is actually (obviously) quite good at doing that.

Our code was the following:

```
    public string CompileMessage(string templateHtml, object modelClass)
    {
        try
        {
            TemplateServiceConfiguration templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = new TemplateResolver(),
                Language = Language.CSharp,
                Debug = true,
            };

            Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService(templateConfig));

            return Razor.Parse(templateHtml, modelCLass);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log4Net.Error("Failed to compile email template using Razor", ex);
            return "Error occurred (" + ex.Message + "). Check the logfile in the vicinity of " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".";
        }
    }
```

Benefits:

- Using Razor gave us the typesafety of giving a model with the "placeholders"
- We had covered XSS and similar attacks as Razor always escapes values unless `@Html.Raw()` was used
- It enabled business users to edit templates relatively safe without worrying about non-html compliant characters
- Razor would take care of culture/ui culture in formatting strings

Comment: This is a Windows forms app.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You can use Razor outside of MVC applications, it is actually the RazorEngine library. See also [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3631971/3394124)